# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1-i}{4}\right)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, soft-question, self-learning

It's been a while since I have taken Calculus II so my experiences on sequences and series has gone down the drain.

I'm trying to find the limit of the sequence $\displaystyle\left(\frac{1-i}{4}\right)^n$ as $n\to \infty$.

I originally was going to try to split everything up, then I got a little worried that I was doing one of those $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2$ phenomena which we all know is not correct. This is where I get stuck.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{1-i}{4} \right)^1=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{i}{4}$$

$$ \left(\frac{1-i}{4} \right)^2=-\frac{i}{8}$$

$$\left(\frac{1-i}{4} \right)^3=-\frac{1}{32}-\frac{i}{32}$$

$$\left(\frac{1-i}{4} \right)^4=-\frac{1}{64}$$

$$...$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} = 0$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Assuming $i=\sqrt{-1}$

$$\left|\frac{1-i}4\right|=\frac{\sqrt{1^2+(-1)^2}}4=\frac{\sqrt2}4\text{ which is }<1$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a^n=?\text{ for }|a|<1$$

Again, $$(x+y)^2=x^2+y^2\iff 2xy=0\implies$$ at least one of $x,y$ is zero

Comment: Maybe you didn't read my question correctly. Remember I stated that the fact that (x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 is generally not a correct statement.

Comment: @Matthew, have you read the whole answer. At the end, I've shown when $$x^2+y^2=(x+y)^2$$ holds true

Comment: Oh sorry, you must have edited it.

Comment: I first thought $i$ was just a variable, now I have deleted my comment. It is better to say $i^2=-1$, because the principal square root is not defined for negative numbers.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: the technique you have used ($|z_{n}| \to 0 \Rightarrow z_{n} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$) precisely works because the limit here is luckily zero. On the other hand reverse always holds ($z_{n} \to a \Rightarrow |z_{n}| \to |a|$). Nice and simple answer (+1).

Comment: Just to comment that if instead of $z=(1-i)/4$ you had some $w$ with $|w|= 1 $ , then the limit would not exist, unless $w = +/- 1 $ , since, geometrically, $w$ would be rotating by $argw$ at every power .